# How do I export a model with seams included?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, obj, seams

I keep trying to export my model and importing it in a new blender project but the seams don't even show.

Comment: Not enough details! What do you mean by "export a model"? - If you export in any of the export formats (fbx, etc.) the file format simply doesn't support Blender's seams. However, you can save you model as a normal Blend file and then use File >Append  to import a mesh from that file into a new Blend file and the seams will be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

### Checking UVs

Do not think that seeing no edges in red means no UVs.

Not all exchange format can carry the edge seams data. But that's not an issue, as they are only used by softwares to generate UVs, they are not the UVs themselves.

In Blender, to check if you have your UVs, simply select your object, switch to Edit Mode, select all the meshes and look at your UV editor if you have UVs.

### Marking Seams

If you have UVs with no seams, you can recreate the seams in your UV editor, hit <kbd>F3</kbd> and search for `Seams from Islands`:

[image]

It will mark the seams as per the UVs.

### Export

Beforehand, if your target is Blender, you don't need to export at all. You can just save as a .blend file, then use File > Link/Append or use the Asset Library to get any data of that .blend into another .blend.

If you need to export in FBX or other exchange formats, make sure Blender's implementation of that format supports it.

You can check this page [Import-Export — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/index.html). If an exporter's manual page specifically mentions exporting UVs, you are sure at least these can do it.

Though the UVs may be said to be exportable, not all exported might give the option to toggle it and just do it by default. So make sure the option is enabled if present.